# Git: How to protect develop/master branch in git-flow (from rookies) via access control?

Tags: git, access-control, git-flow

The previous days I read https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow to which I have a a question.

If one uses the Feature Branch or the Gitflow Branch Workflows in a project: Is there an option that a user pushes a feature branch as a tracking feature branch to origin issues a pull request and ONLY the maintainer of the project is able to merge the tracking feature branch into the master (Feature Branch Workflow) or the develop (Gitlow Branch Workflow)?

In other words: Is it possible to assign branches to users so that one does not have immediate need for the Forking Workflow if one does not want to over-complicate things but still have a guaranteed code review which secures the master/develop branch from rookies?

Comment: I think you have to implement restrictions with hooks if you want to do it yourself. I've used [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) previously to add security to some of my repositories. I'd recommend you to give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Remote git services like github, bitbucket, gitlab, vsts, etc., have the ability to "protect" branches to prevent pushing to them directly or deleting the branch. If you wanted to simulate something like this on your local machine, you can use git hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Example to prevent commits to master: https://gist.github.com/aaronhoffman/ffbfd36928f9336be2436cffe39feaec

pre-commit file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# prevent commit to local master branch

branch=`git symbolic-ref HEAD`
if [ "$branch" = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
    echo "pre-commit hook: Can not commit to the local master branch."
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

pre-push file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Prevent push to remote master branch

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$remote_ref" = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
        echo "pre-push hook: Can not push to remote master branch."
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```